# Coefficients for all levels of a categorical factor unchanged in lmer after adding variables

Tags: r, lme4, multi-level

I am estimating lmer models with subject random effects for a within-subject design study. I have a measurement of a dependent variable for each subject in three different treatment conditions, resulting in a balanced design. In addition to the treatment dummies I also have control variables in the lmer model.

First thing that stuck out is that all treatment dummies had equal standard errors, which has already been asked and answered here:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/170018/equal-standard-errors-for-all-levels-of-a-categorical-factor-in-lmer

The second thing that stuck out was that the coefficients of the treatment dummies do not change if I add control variables to the model.

Here the behavior of lmer is reproduced with some simulated data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)

#Some data:
id <- rep(1:50) #subject id
dependent_1 <- rnorm(50,10,5) #dependent measure in treatment 1
dependent_2 <- rnorm(50,18,3) #dependent measure in treatment 2
dependent_3 <- rnorm(50,28,4) #dependent measure in treatment 3
control_a <- rnorm(50, 100, 5) #first control
control_b <- rnorm(50, 200,33) #second control

df <- data.frame(id, dependent_1, dependent_2, dependent_3, control_a, control_b) #make dataframe

#Reshape to long form
df_long <- pivot_longer(df, 
                        cols = starts_with("dependent_"), 
                        names_to = c(".value","treatment"),
                        names_sep = "\\_")

#Treatment to factor
df_long$treatment <- as.factor(df_long$treatment)

#LMER Models
lmer_model.1 <- lmer(dependent ~ treatment +(1|id), data = df_long, REML = FALSE) #Model with treatment dummies only
lmer_model.2 <- lmer(dependent ~ treatment + control_a + control_b + (1|id), data = df_long, REML = FALSE) #Model with treatment dummies and controls
```

I get the following results:

```
===============================================================
                            Model 1               Model 2             
---------------------------------------------------------------
(Intercept)             9.246 (0.567) ***    17.535 (7.796) *  
treatment2              8.157 (0.787) ***     8.157 (0.787) ***
treatment3             20.030 (0.787) ***    20.030 (0.787) ***
control_a                                    -0.067 (0.072)    
control_b                                    -0.008 (0.011)    
---------------------------------------------------------------
AIC                   852.194               854.977            
BIC                   867.247               876.051            
Log Likelihood       -421.097              -420.488            
Num. obs.             150                   150                
Num. groups: id        50                    50                
Var: id (Intercept)     0.596                 0.457            
Var: Residual          15.492                15.492            
===============================================================
*** p < 0.001; ** p < 0.01; * p < 0.05
```

Can anyone explain to me the reason why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently about statistics, not programming. Consider asking it on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) instead.

It seems that the answer to your question lies in the way you set up your example data. An additional control/predictor variable X2 only influences estimates of another, previously included predictor X1 they are (at least a bit) correlated. In reality, this is mostly true, as you hardly get *r* = .00 correlations in real-life data. But you set up your data in a way such that `treatment` is orthogonal to `control_a` and `control_b`. Therefore, including either control does not impact the coefficients of the treatment dummies.

Comment: Thanks, I moved my question to stackexchange (sorry, kind of new here). 
I think you are right, but this should also hold for real from repeated measures, as personal characteristics should not be correlated with the treatment dummies.